# Remember Scroll Position Angular Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am using angular 2 and typescript to make the front-end. I have used md-tab-group from the angular material library to make tabs. I want to remember the scroll position of each tab and go to that particular position after tab switch. I can correctly get the scroll position but I am unable to set the scroll position. I think the selectChange or focusChange events are setting the scroll position to 0. When I type the command to scroll to a particular position in the console, it works perfectly. And the below code also works once in a while. Increasing the timeout increases the probability of its working, though I am not sure.

TabService:

```
  public scrollTab() {
    let el = document.getElementById('items-container');
    this.tabs[this.currentTab].scrollPosition = el.scrollTop;
    console.log(this.tabs[this.currentTab]);
  }

  public setScroll() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let el = document.getElementById('items-container');
      if(el.scrollTop !== undefined ) {
        el.scrollTop = this.tabs[this.currentTab].scrollPosition;
      }
      console.log(this.tabs[this.currentTab]);
    }, 200);
  }

  public switchTab(index: number) {
    this.currentTab = index;
    this.location.go('/' + this.tabs[index].path);
    this.displayEditor.next(false);
  }
```

TabComponent:

```
<md-tab-group class="tabbar"
     (focusChange)="tabService.scrollTab()"
     (selectChange)="tabService.switchTab($event.index); tabService.setScroll()"
     [selectedIndex]="tabService.currentTab" #tabgroup>
```